# Access Selenium LocalStorage nodejs

Tags: node.js, selenium

Im trying to retrieve a value from a key using selenium, i've been searching for hours without anybody or anything telling me how i could do that, 
What im trying to retrieve looks like this which i obtained while typing F12 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywYkL.png
Which is on the client side.

Comment: Could you please share the portion of your code that you trying to use to retrieve the localStorage?

Comment: @HelderRobalo Here you have the entire code : https://pastebin.com/TfkCgY5u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
driver.executeScript(
        "localStorage.getItem(arguments[0])", key
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
window.localStorage.getItem("BrowserHandoffStore");
```

Example here:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("test", false);
window.localStorage.getItem("test")
```

Output:

```
false
```

Comment: According that im using a node package ? Because localeStorage isn't defined.
@Andrei

Comment: By the way, i also tried with the node package "node-localstorage" but it returns me null, i don't think it does target my current open browser, full code here : https://pastebin.com/TfkCgY5u

Comment: Yes, I did a mistake, please check my updated code. It should work on client side

Comment: Getting error : Window is not defined. Remember that im using node.js.

Comment: did you installed `npm install node-localstorage`?

Comment: Yes. Here is my current script so far : https://hastebin.com/awosixoyug.js

Answer (score 1):

for who maybe still are looking for the solution:
you can use web driver executeScript

```
async function(localStorageFieldName){
      await driver.executeScript(function(){
         return localStorage.getItem(arguments[0])
      },localStorageFieldName)
}
```

reference to executeScript : [link](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/ie_exports_Driver.html#executeScript)